# Change Image.core.jpeglib version in PIL on ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, python-imaging-library

I am trying to deploy a model which uses the pillow (PIL) library on ubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS). The model was built on windows, and i have since discovered that PIL returns different arrays when reading the same image between Ubuntu and Windows.

This seems to be because of the jpeglib version (9 not 8). Does anyone know how to change this version so i can replicate the same results on a linux mahcine?

Thanks!

Comment: All supported versions of Ubuntu have libjpeg9 available https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libjpeg9&searchon=names .... Ubuntu 18.04 example: Default is libjpeg8 . And the package `libjpeg9` can be installed too. No conflicts. ........... All libjpeg →  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libjpeg&searchon=names

Comment: tak @KnudLarsen!  thanks for such a fast response. I need python (pillow) to invoke libjpeg 8 whilst it is currently calling 9. do you know where this is being called or how I force the default be 8?

Comment: Please edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68474269/edit to include Ubuntu version. ...... A solution could be to make sure the Ubuntu python-pillow is built with libjpeg8-dev . Alternatively build the unknown model on Ubuntu.

Comment: Updated :) Im running 20.04 - jpeglib8 is installed but not called. Ill try to build pillow in a new conda environment

Answer (score 1):

Solved by building Pillow from source with jpeglib-8 installed. This means jpegs loaded with the same decoder match.